# Using layout view in Express with Consolidate and Mustache

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

I just started going through Node using Express and finally got Consolidate JS working properly to use Mustache as the templating view system per the instructions on the [Consolidate JS Github page](https://github.com/visionmedia/consolidate.js).

Mustache is loading properly, but I'm now wondering how to include the layout file along in the rendering of the template. The default Jade system loads the content of the .render method inside of the layout.jade file. I'm just wondering how to do the same, but with Mustache. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Code:

**index.js**

```
 exports.index = function(req, res){
    res.render('index', { title: "Work pl0x?" });
 });
```

**index.mustache**

## Welcome to {{title}}

I just want the index.mustache content to come in the "{{content}}" portion of the code below (layout.mustache). How can I do this?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Project Name | {{title}}</title>
 <link href="/stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>

 <body>

     {{content}}

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Have you got the answer?

Comment: @Boris I was not able to do it. Went back to an older version of Express that's not in RC status and using EJS instead.

Answer (score 3):

One way to get that behaviour (kind of) is this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  res.render('layout', { title: "Work pl0x?", partials: { content: "index" });
});
```

Then write like this in your layout.html

```
<body>
  {{>content}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept of layouts have been removed from express as of 3.0. Here's a [reference link](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) with more info.

Comment: or rather, it's been delegated to the individual template engines. But how do you handle layout w/consolidate, or mustache/consolidate?